# Feed reader - blog subscriptions

Tags: blogging, feed

Lot of times you will find a team writing good set of blogs, and if you are not interested in the content from one or more blogger in that group, is there any feed reader that allows me to unsubscribe to a particular blog in the group?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yep, (coincidentally named) [Feed Reader](http://www.feedreader.com/) can do this with what they call a "smartfeed". You will want to filter by **Author**.

Here's an example I used to filter questions to only yours:

[image]

Comment: Yes this reader does exactly what I am looking for. Thank you! I wish feeddemon does the same.